# How to do a sum in jooq

Tags: java, sum, field, aggregate, jooq

Hello I have a method to calculate values from database in which I use jooq then iterate over the result to do the summing, aggregating of some fields.  My question is can I do this all in a jooq statement instead of having to walk my resultSet and add them up manually?  Here is what I have so far: Thanks.

```
BigDecimal dealDiscountAmt = BigDecimal.ZERO;
BigDecimal standardAmtOneTimeTrue = BigDecimal.ZERO;
BigDecimal standardAmtOneTimeFalse = BigDecimal.ZERO;
BigDecimal oneTimeFalseX12 = BigDecimal.ZERO;

/** Dao for jooq access to db. */
@Resource(name = "dmDaoContext")
protected DSLContext dmDao_;


List<JDealMetricWorkflowCriteriaRecord> retValList = new ArrayList<JDealMetricWorkflowCriteriaRecord>();
JDealMetricWorkflowCriteriaRecord newDealRecord = new JDealMetricWorkflowCriteriaRecord();

List<JMetricServicePxvRecord> records = dmDao_.selectFrom(METRIC_SERVICE_PXV)
    .where(METRIC_SERVICE_PXV.DEAL_ID.eq(dealId), METRIC_SERVICE_PXV.PRODUCED_DATETIME.eq(whenProduced))
    .fetch();

for (JMetricServicePxvRecord record : records) {
  //sum all dealDiscounts
  dealDiscountAmt = dealDiscountAmt.add(record.getStandardTotalPxv().subtract(record.getProposedTotalPxv());

  if (record.getOneTime()) {
    //sum all dealDiscounts if oneTime is true
    standardAmtOneTimeTrue = standardAmtOneTimeTrue.add(record.getStandardTotalPxv().subtract(record.getProposedTotalPxv());
  } else {
    //sum all dealDiscounts if oneTime is false
    standardAmtOneTimeFalse = standardAmtOneTimeFalse.add(record.getStandardTotalPxv().subtract(record.getProposedTotalPxv());
  }
}

oneTimeFalseX12 = standardAmtOneTimeFalse.multiply(new BigDecimal("12"));

newDealRecord.setDealDiscount(dealDiscountAmt);
newDealRecord.setAnnualizedDealDiscount(standardAmtOneTimeTrue.add(oneTimeFalseX12));

retValList.add(newDealRecord);
```

Answer (score 5):

jOOQ can do everything that SQL can do.

#### So, let's first look at the SQL query that you want to run

The following is standard SQL that runs on every database:

```sql
SELECT
  SUM(standard_total_pxv - proposed_total_pxv) 
    AS deal_discount,
  SUM(CASE WHEN one_time  = 1 THEN standard_total_pxv - propsed_total_pxv END) +
  SUM(CASE WHEN one_time != 1 THEN standard_total_pxv - propsed_total_pxv END) * 12 
    AS annualized_deal_discount
FROM metric_service_pxv
WHERE deal_id = :dealId AND produced_datetime = :whenProduced
```

I'm assuming that your `ONE_TIME` column is a `NUMBER(1)`. If you're using a `BOOLEAN` type (in case your database supports that), then you can use the column directly as a predicate:

```
... WHEN one_time THEN ...
```

The `SUM(CASE ...)` idiom makes use of the fact that SQL `SUM()` only aggregates non-`NULL` values. So, all the undesired rows are removed from the sum by making them `NULL`, depending on the value of `ONE_TIME`

#### Now with jOOQ:

```java
// Assuming this static import
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

And then:

```java
// Aliasing the table for brevity
MetricServicePxv m = METRIC_SERVICE_PXV.as("m");

// Reusing this sum several times:
AggregateFunction<BigDecimal> sum = sum(m.STANDARD_TOTAL_PXV.sub(m.PROPOSED_TOTAL_PXV));

// Here's your result:
Record2<BigDecimal, BigDecimal> result =
dmDao_
  .select(
    sum.as("DEAL_DISCOUNT"),
    sum.filterWhere(m.ONE_TIME.eq(1)).add(
    sum.filterWhere(m.ONE_TIME.ne(1)).mul(12)).as("ANNUALIZED_DEAL_DISCOUNT"))
  .from(m)
  .where(m.DEAL_ID.eq(dealId).and(m.PRODUCED_DATETIME.eq(whenProduced)))
  .fetchOne();
```

#### A note on `FILTER (WHERE ...)`

I'm using the [`AggregateFunction.filterWhere()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/AggregateFilterStep.html#filterWhere-org.jooq.Condition...-) feature here, for simplicity. [`SUM(...) FILTER (WHERE ...)` is a SQL standard language feature](https://blog.jooq.org/2014/12/30/the-awesome-postgresql-9-4-sql2003-filter-clause-for-aggregate-functions/), which is currently only implemented in PostgreSQL and HSQLDB. In all other databases, the `SUM(CASE ...)` aggregate function is generated instead.

Comment: Lukas, when I do sum.filterWhere(m.ONE_TIME.eq(true)), I get the error saying "The method filterWhere(Condition) is undefined for the type Field<BigDecimal>

Comment: I added a cast (AggregateFilterStep<BigDecimal> sum and the error goes away.  Is this cool?

Comment: @hln98: You're welcome ;) My bad. I should have assigned the `sum` to a variable of type `AggregateFunction<BigDecimal>`. Your workaround is valid too, but the cast is not needed if the variable already has the right type.

Comment: Lukas,  I ran the query and the result is (251, 251) where it should be (251, 3015).  Not sure why it didn't multiply  251 by int 12 for the Annualized_Discount.

Comment: I suspect that `sum.filterWhere(m.ONE_TIME.ne(1))` yields zero, then. Perhaps your predicates are wrong?

Comment: I use sum.filterWhere(m.ONE_TIME.ne(true)) and it sums correctly.  I had 12 as an int so that was why it didn't multiply by 12 correctly.  I corrected the 12 as BigDecimal and the output still not correct as now I get (251.31, 3267.03) where I should get (251.31, 3015.72).  Any idea?

Comment: @hln98: I just copied / translated your formula from Java to SQL, maybe it wasn't correct in the first place? What you did there is this: `standardAmtOneTimeTrue.add(oneTimeFalseX12)`. I don't know what this means, business-wise, so you'll have to figure that out on your side...